# how use SCRAM-SHA-256 to connect database by jdbc in PostgresSQL

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

there
 I'm trying to test SCRAM-SHA-256 in jdbc.

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        String url = "jdbc:postgresql://192.168.56.101:1521/gisdb";
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("user", "pguser");
        String scram = "SCRAM-SHA-256$4096:QNTBYMpbvZjbOx5RLM7rvA==$tuBD7Ek7niK8jyiuwjCGLH2EurqMNoIaclZhOXohyik=:2b0Ow951/1OPKsqzaGLWPyT+wVIXOs9dvY8TF2eTCVM=";
        props.setProperty("password", scram);
//        props.setProperty("password", "*******");

        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, props);
        String databaseProductVersion = conn.getMetaData().getDatabaseProductVersion();
        System.out.println(databaseProductVersion);
    }
```

my `pg_hba.conf`:

```
hostssl all             all             192.168.0.0/16          scram-sha-256
#hostssl all             all             192.168.0.0/16          trust
```

`select rolname,rolpassword from pg_authid;` it shows:

```
          rolname          |                                                              rolpassword
---------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 pg_monitor                |
 pg_read_all_settings      |
 pg_read_all_stats         |
 pg_stat_scan_tables       |
 pg_read_server_files      |
 pg_write_server_files     |
 pg_execute_server_program |
 pg_signal_backend         |
 pguser                    | SCRAM-SHA-256$4096:PZNbiF6I5G1SVcoN9sTjJw==$xe8jrBS9iUn0ldoIV8moaAod06sYRbxsyyQaUbiuSQE=:2tpLS+eL1brme0Il0wcnsllkDBfDkaQ/II7iVJ3ecxM=
 test                      |
 postgres                  | SCRAM-SHA-256$4096:o1lyjT/acTglIuLsp6TF3Q==$pdWLZ8DuceZDwr9jla0WPzXXa3N3kWrjh9cPnrloP3w=:6hd8Ib7Od+ZZenItVoH4L+26oSiBxqp63WxO82PeonM=
```

when I use `scram-sha-256` encrypted password string or prue password in java code to connect, in log file, it shows  `FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "pguser"` .
when I change method to `trust` in `pg_hba.conf`, it works.

How to use `scram-sha-256` method to password connect?
My JDBC driver version is `postgresql-42.2.12.jar`

Comment: Which version of the JDBC driver are you using?

Comment: latest, `postgresql-42.2.12.jar`

Comment: Security would be a joke if you could use the authentication hash from the database as your password.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You must supply the clear text password, not the SCRAM hash.

Answer (score 3):

From what I understand as a solution. This is a multi step process,
All steps defined below:

- **Firstly**, we need to have SCRAM as the encryption type on db. For this you need to edit the file - **postgresql.conf** and change the value of password_encryption as : **password_encryption = scram-sha-256**

Restart your postgres server after this change

- **Second**, update the passwords in db and verify if they are in scram encryption. 
  By default the db passwords are encrypted with MD5, after updating
  the db configuration, you need to do update these encrypted strings
  that are stored in the db. Run sql query : **alter user 
  with encrypted password ;**  Verify the change
  by running the query : **select rolname,rolpassword from pg_authid;**
  You should see the password column having string in the format
  **SCRAM-***
- **Third**, we need to enable scram config for incoming client connections. For that edit the file : **pg_hba.conf** . Refer to the screenshot below :

[image: **Change the method value as in the image**]
Rest, your jdbc program should work (with just a minor edit : **String scram = "plaintext-password";** ) keeping in mind that the right versions of jdbc drivers are used.